# can i use pixabay images to psd make mockups and sell them on freepik

Tags: images, background, mockup

Can I Use Pixabay Images As Background To Make psd Mockups And Sell Them on **Freepik**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a **legal** question, not a design question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Graphic Design Stack Exchange! I would look at Pixabay's [license](https://pixabay.com/service/license/). Glancing over it, it doesn't seem to disallow it though. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks For your Answer,, But The Thing is That, I Need to be sure,, Coz i don't wanna get any copyright issue or something like that,, hope you get my question

Comment: @ibnul I read over the license; the definitive answer is **yes**. You, as long as you edit them can use Pixabay images. Pexels and Unsplash both have similar licensing too.